# Use Mobile Broadband USB as Wireless Adapter USB - HUAWEI E173

Tags: wireless, usb, 64-bit, adapter

I have an Mobile Broadband USB (HUAWEI E173), which can also work as a WiFi Adapter USB.

The problem is that Ubuntu 12.04 only recognizes it as an Mobile Broadband USB, not as an Wireless Adapter USB, is there a way to "trick" Ubuntu to recognize my USB as a Wireless Adapter?

Thanks in advance.

Notes:

- I used the `lsusb` command and got this:

  ```
  `Bus 002 Device 009: ID 12d1:1c23 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.`
  ```
- I have 64-bit Ubuntu Installed, so it may just be a driver problem.

Comment: How about take out the sim card?

Comment: Nope, I tried and the USB turns off if I remove the SIM card.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1741762) you? Have see that post?

Comment: I'm not alexfish, although I will try the solutions in the post, Thanks!